# Bitmap image are visible in Qt Designer but I can't see them after compiling in QDevelop IDE

Tags: qt, designer

In qt-designer I loaded bitmap images and in preview I am able to view the images. But after compiling in qdevelop IDE, I could not see the images at all.

Is there any procedure to load the bitmaps in to qdevelop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be wanting to add the bitmaps to a resource file, using Qt's resource system, if you want to be able to use them in Designer and also have them work in your compiled application correctly.  I've not used it, but the examples look fairly straightforward, and it appears QDevelop supports the resource system to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Qt to use required images plugins?

> [-no-gif] [-qt-gif] [-no-libtiff] [-system-libtiff] [-no-libpng] [-qt-libpng] [-system-libpng] [-no-libmng] [-qt-libmng] [-system-libmng] [-no-libjpeg] [-qt-libjpeg] [-system-libjpeg]